# AngularJS : execute code after his job

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

I want to execute some code after AngularJS finished to change the HTML after an event. I've tried to do the following:

```
angular.module('ngC', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.directive("carousel", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("imgs", function (value)
        {
            //  Here my code
        });
    };
});
```

The problem is that my code is execute before AngularJS replace `{{}}` code but I want execute it after.

Comment: Don't you want to make something like scope.$watch(attrs.imgs, …) instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on: [jQuery doesn't work in AngularJS ng-view properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527885/jquery-doesnt-work-in-angularjs-ng-view-properly/15674655#15674655)

```
// (inside some function with $rootScope available)
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    // ... (multiview init code here) ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare if newValue is different from oldValue in the $watch listening function, this will indicate if something has changed or not.

```
scope.$watch("imgs", function (newValue, oldValue)
{
    if(newValue !== oldValue) {         
       // Here my code
    }
});
```

EDIT: From the docs

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

Comment: In fact I want to run a JQuery command (JQuery Raty) so I need to as the final "HTML".